# How to remove first 2 characters in a string if it has a '-'

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

`p_officialTitle` in this case usually equals something like `"1-Application"` or `"Application"`. If it has a dash, it has to be removed, and the number before it needs to be removed as well. The `Mid` and `Find` methods are not working. Is there any other recommendation?

```
DIIXDAPI_INDEX_FIELD_TYPE* p_OfficialTitle = Find(param->documentIndexFieldList, D_OFFICIAL_TITLE);
                    
//Name a Temporary CString; in that CString remove anything with a '-' --- This cleans up the naming convention
    
CString strTemp = p_OfficialTitle->szFieldValue.Get();
    
p_OfficialTitle->szFieldValue.Set(strTemp.Mid(strTemp.Find(_T('-'))));
```

Comment: We don't know what these functions `Mid` and `Find` actually do since we don't know the class `CString`

Comment: @Baruch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019

Comment: @cdhowie Then please add the relevant tags (I don't know if it is MFC or ATL or both). I am not familiar with those and came to try to answer seeing the c++ tag

Comment: @Baruch It's not my question, why are you yelling at me?

Comment: @cdhowie (PLEASE READ THIS COMMENT IN A WHISPER) I am not yelling at anyone. I was asking for a correction to be made that I am not qualified to make myself. Since you seemed to be qualified to make it, I tagged you in my comment (the OP gets notified of comments anyway)

Comment: @Baruch Pretty sure the link was provided to you for purely informative purposes.

Answer (score 1):

[`CString::Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019#find) returns a 0-based index, returning `-1` if the character/substring is not found.

[`CString::Mid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019#mid) returns a substring starting at a specified index.

You are not handling the case when `Find()` returns `-1`, such as for `"Application"`.  You can't pass `-1` as the starting index to `Mid()`, so you need to check for that condition.  And since you want to remove everything up to *and including* the `-` if it is found, you need to pass its index *+1* to `Mid()`, eg:

```
CString strTemp = p_OfficialTitle->szFieldValue.Get();
    
int index = strTemp.Find(_T('-'));
if (index != -1) { // <-- add this
    p_OfficialTitle->szFieldValue.Set(strTemp.Mid(index+1)); // <-- add +1
}
```

Or, you can simply get rid of the `if` (if you don't mind a redundant `Set()` call if `-` is not found), eg:

```
CString strTemp = p_OfficialTitle->szFieldValue.Get();

p_OfficialTitle->szFieldValue.Set(strTemp.Mid(strTemp.Find(_T('-'))+1));
```

Since `Find('-') + 1` is `0` for `"Application"` and is `2` for `"1-Application"`, so `Mid(0)` will return the entire string if `-` is not found, and `Mid(2)` will return only the remaining characters if `-` is found.

Comment: Hey that worked! Thank your for your help and being so thorough!